# How to create an object with the constructor with parameter

Tags: c++, constructor

For some reason whenever I try running my code it always call the default constructor but it should be calling the constructor with parameters.

```
#include "pokemon.h"

 int main()
{
    int choice;

    cout<<"input 1 2 or 3"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;

    if(choice==1||choice==2||choice==3)
    {
        pokemon(choice);
    }

}
```

in my headerfile i have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class pokemon{
public:
    pokemon();//default constructor
    pokemon(int a);
    ~pokemon();//desconstructor
    pokemon(const pokemon& c);
    void train();
    void feed();
    bool isnothappy();
    string getName();//accessor for the name
    int getPowerlevel();//accessor for the power level
    string getColor();//accessor for the color
    string getType();//accessor
    int getHappylevel();//accessor
    static int getNumObjects();
    void set_type(string);//mutator
    void set_color(string);//mutator
    void set_power_level(int);//mutator
    void set_happy_level(int);//mutator
    void set_name(string);//mutator
private:
    string name;
    string color;
    string type;
    int power_level;
    int happy_level;
    static int numberobject;
};
```

and in my other .cpp file i have

```
int pokemon::numberobject=0;//initialize static member variable

pokemon::pokemon(){//default constructor
    name="pikachu";
    color="yellow";
    type="electric";
    power_level=0;
    happy_level=1;

    cout<<"The default constructor is being called"<<endl;
    ++numberobject;
}

pokemon::pokemon(int a)
{

    if(a==0)
    {
        name="Pikachu";
        color="yellow";
        type="electric";
        power_level=1;
        happy_level=1;
    }


    else if(a==1)
    {
        name="Bulbasaur";
        color="green";
        type="grass";
        power_level=1;
        happy_level=1;
    }


    else if(a==2)
    {
        name="Charmander";
        color="red";
        type="fire";
        power_level=1;
        happy_level=1;
    }

    else if(a==3)
    {
        name="Squritle";
        color="blue";
        type="water";
        power_level=1;
        happy_level=1;
    }

    cout<<"Congratulations you have chosen "<<getName()<<". This " <<getColor()<<" "<<getType()<<" pokemon is really quite energetic!"<<endl;
    ++numberobject;
}

pokemon::~pokemon()
{
    //cout<<"the destructor is now being called"<<endl;
    //cout<<"the number of objects before the destructor is "<<pokemon::getNumObjects()<<endl;
    --numberobject;
    cout<<"Now you have a total number of "<<pokemon::getNumObjects()<<endl;
}

pokemon::pokemon(const pokemon& c)//copy constructor
{
    name=c.name;
    color=c.color;
    type=c.type;
    power_level=c.power_level;
    happy_level=c.happy_level;
    ++numberobject;
}
```

I have both my constructors declared and defined in my other files but this darn thing always calls the default constructor

Comment: `pokemon(choice);`  What does this line do?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie pokemon(choice) doesnt even get excuted for some reason it just goes to the default constructor

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of `pokemon.h`

Comment: That's not what I really asked.  What is that line supposed to do?   How do you create objects in C++?  Where is the *instance* of the pokemon object where that is being assigned?  I don't see it.  Shouldn't it look something like this: `pokemon myObject(choice);`?  Also, please post pokemon.h.

Comment: Assuming `pokemon` is your class name, did you try `pokemon a_pokemon(choice);`?

Comment: @dlavila oh shoot ur right I didn't try that! That was dumb on my part! but thank u and paul for helping me out once again! I'll try to be more observant next time!

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
pokemon(choice);
```

means the same as:

```
pokemon choice;
```

It declares a variable called `choice` of type `pokemon`, and there are no arguments given to the constructor.  (You're allowed to put extra parentheses in declarations in some places).

---

If you meant to declare a variable where `choice` is a constructor argument then you have to write:

```
pokemon foo(choice);
```

If you meant to create a temporary object (which will be immediately destroyed) with `choice` as argument, you can write `(pokemon)choice;`, or `pokemon(+choice);`, or since C++11, `pokemon{choice};`.

---

This issue with ambiguity between declarations and non-declarations can arise any time a statement begins with a type-name followed by `(`. The rule is that if it is syntactically correct for a declaration then it is treated as a declaration. See [most-vexing-parse](/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse) for other such cases.